# Sidekiq: ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I guess [this question](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ArgumentError%3A%20When%20assigning%20attributes%2C%20you%20must%20pass%20a%20hash%20as%20an%20argument.&oq=ArgumentError%3A%20When%20assigning%20attributes%2C%20you%20must%20pass%20a%20hash%20as%20an%20argument.&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.597j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) is common with Rails 4, but my situation is different.

I am using Sidekiq to delay the creation of jobs; think this is possible as with simple data, it works. By means of simple data:

```
def perform
 Foo.create(bar: "staff")
end
```

Here's my data with issues:

**supports_controller.rb:**

```
def create
 params = support_params // seems to be issues here?
 DelayedJobs.perform_in(1.minutes, current_user.id, params)
 ...
end

private

  def support_params
   params.require(:support).permit(:foo1, :foo2, :foo3)
  end
```

**app/workers/delayed_jobs.rb:**

```
class DelayedJobs
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(user_id, params)
    u = User.find(user_id)
    support = u.supports.build(params)
    Support.create(support) // create and save to db
  end
end
```

Via web (localhost:3000/sidekiq/scheduled, I see the details. Great. But after a minute it goes to retries with the error. Any help on this one?

**EDIT:**

In the sidekiq web argument:

> 40, {"foo1"=>"a", "foo2"=>"b", "foo3"=>"c"}

Why is that the `user_id` (40) is outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with Sidekiq; it's an ActiveRecord problem with this line:

`Support.create(support)`

`create` only takes a hash, but you're giving it a `Support`.

This should work:

```
class DelayedJobs
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(user_id, params)
    u = User.find(user_id)
    u.supports.create!(params) # `create!` will raise an error if the save fails; allowing you to catch invalid params
  end
end
```

Protip: you can eliminate Sidekiq as a suspect by running the body of your `perform` method in a Rails console. You'll see that you get the same error even when Sidekiq isn't involved.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you call save method on support object because when you are using build method it returns a new instance of support so you need only to save it.

```
class DelayedJobs
include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(user_id, params)
    u = User.find(user_id)
    support = u.supports.build(params)
    support.save // save to db
  end
end
```

In your controller try to change params to:

```
def create
  params = params[:support]
```

Comment: can you please post the error message that you are currently having ?

Comment: Those are the arguments passed to the worker, I meant what's the error stack you are getting, you can check your sidekiq console to see what's the error :)

Comment: The error is as in title im afraid. Nothing else to post.

Comment: Check my updated answer for the controller change, to answer why 40 (the user id) is outside the hash because those represent the argument of your worker perform method (user_id, params)

Comment: Thanks for your support, marouenB. Kitkat's `create` did the trick.